# Nichols plot confusion

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, bode-plot, control-theory, nyquist-plot

The transfer function is \$F(p)=10/(p^2+2p+1).\$

Using Wolfram Alpha, the Nichols plot shows that the argument \$\to -\pi\$ when \$\omega \to +\infty\$.

However, calculating the argument on paper gives
\$-\arctan(2w/(1-w^2))\$
which \$\to 0\$ when \$w \to +\infty\$.

Where is the error, mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

Probably no error with the math, but realize that the chart is not a grid. It looks like the chart below. So if charting by hand make sure the grid is a Log scale *of the magnitude* or \$20\log_{10}(|G(s)|)\$ on one axis and phase on the other. If the closed loop transfer function is given, then a nichols plot is the open loop version, so it will need to be converted from closed loop to open loop.

[image]
Source: http://courses.me.metu.edu.tr/courses/me442/handout.html

Comment: I didn't try plotting a Nichols grid, the problem is that when I plotted a Nichols PLOT of my transfer function, I got a graphical result that didn't match with the calculus on paper (the limit of the argument when w->infinity)....

Answer (score 0):

Look at the real and imaginary parts:

```
{re, im} = ComplexExpand@ReIm[10/(p^2 + 2 p + 1) /. p -> I w] // Simplify
```

> $$\left\{-\frac{10 \left(w^2-1\right)}{\left(w^2+1\right)^2},-\frac{20
>    w}{\left(w^2+1\right)^2}\right\}$$

The real part starts off positive, becomes zero when \$w=1\$, and then becomes negative. The imaginary part starts off at \$0\$ and then becomes negative. Thus the phase starts at the positive real axis, goes through the fourth quadrant, then the first, and ends up on the negative real axis.

Calling [ArcTan](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html) without cancelling the sign shows this.

```
Plot[ArcTan[re, im]/Degree, {w, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"freq.", "phase"}]
```

> [image]

If you cancel, you lose the sign information and get the result you are getting. This is not correct.

```
ArcTan[im/re]
```

> $$ \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 w}{w^2-1}\right)$$

```
Plot[%/Degree, {w, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"freq.", "phase"}]
```

> [image]

Comment: I really don't understand your answer. The expression of the argument is the expression of the imaginary?? (Of what??) I read the script but I don't understand the result and your analysis....

Comment: And I'm not understanding your question. "The expression of the argument is the expression of the imaginary"? Please refer to specific things I have in my answer, so I can follow your question.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
F(j\omega)=\frac{10}{-\omega^2+2j\omega+1}=10\frac{(1-\omega^2)-2\omega j}
{((1-\omega^2)+2\omega j)((1-\omega^2)-2\omega j)}
$$
$$
=10\frac{(1-\omega^2)-2\omega j}
{(1-\omega^2)^2+4\omega^2}
=10\frac{1-\omega^2-2\omega j}
{1-2\omega^2+\omega^4+4\omega^2}
=10\frac{1-\omega^2-2\omega j}
{1+2\omega^2+\omega^4}
$$
$$
=\frac{10}{(1+\omega^2)^2}(1-\omega^2-2\omega j).
$$
Since multiplication by \$\frac{10}{(1+\omega^2)^2}\$ does not change the value of an argument,
consider
\$\arg(1-\omega^2-2\omega j)=\alpha
\$.
The trigonometric form of \$1-\omega^2-2\omega j\$ is
$$
|1-\omega^2-2\omega j|
\left( 
\underbrace{\frac{1-\omega^2}{|1-\omega^2-2\omega j|}}_{\cos\alpha}+
\underbrace{\frac{-2\omega}{|1-\omega^2-2\omega j|}}_{\sin\alpha}j
 \right).
$$
This implies that
$$
\lim_{\omega\to+\infty}\cos \alpha=
\lim_{\omega\to+\infty}
\frac{1-\omega^2}{|1-\omega^2-2\omega j|}= -1,
$$
$$
\lim_{\omega\to+\infty}\sin \alpha=
\lim_{\omega\to+\infty}
\frac{-2\omega}{|1-\omega^2-2\omega j|}= 0.
$$
Hence, calculating the argument on paper does not give \$0\$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't understand your reasoning. You showed that alpha is |alpha| x (cos/|alpha|+j sin/|alpha|) and proved that cos-> -1 and sin->0 when w->inf. What about |alpha|, the one that's multiplied in the beginning, |alpha| -> inf. When w->inf. But what does all of this tell us about the argument's limit???

Comment: @A.Bukhari You showed that alpha is |alpha| x (cos/|alpha|+j sin/|alpha|)  - no, it is not so. You are confusing the value \$1-\omega^2-2\omega j\$ and its argument value \$\alpha\$.

Comment: @A.Bukhari I have updated the answer to make it clearer what \$\cos \alpha\$ and \$\sin\alpha\$ are

Comment: @A.Bukhari Multliplication by \$|1-\omega^2-2\omega j|\$ does not change the argument because it is real and positive.